# Dart Language: GET (favicon issue)

Tags: dart, dart-io

I have a Dart application running on the server side. It is listening at a specific port and working fine. The problem is: my listener is responding to the GET of the favorite icon (favicon).

How can I avoid that?

EDIT: give some code example.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
    print("Starting server.");
    HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.LOOPBACK_IP_V4, 4041)
        .then(listenForRequests)
        .catchError((e) => print (e.toString()));
}

listenForRequests(HttpServer _server) {
    _server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
        if (request.method == 'GET') {
            handleGet(request);
        } else {
            request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED;
            request.response.write("Unsupported request: ${request.method}.");
            request.response.close();
        }
    },
    onDone: () => print('No more requests.'),
    onError: (e) => print(e.toString()) );
}

void handleGet(HttpRequest request) {
    int requestNumber = 1;
    print(requestNumber); // This shows me the request number. Just for information.
    print(request.uri); // This shows me the request from the client browser.
    request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.OK;
    request.response.close();
}
```

This is the output of this code:

1

> /SOME_REQUEST_FROM_THE_BROWSER

2

> /favicon.ico

Comment: So you application mimics a webserver?

Comment: @Robert Actually I'm working on a web application that will handle file operations (creating, opening, saving) on the server side, and as Dart cannot run dart:io on the client side, I have to run a HTTP request listener on the server. I'm really new to Dart and I don't know if this is the right way to work with client-server operations, but if it is, I have to avoid responding to GET requests that doesn't matter to my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the requested resource and generate proper response for requests to 'favicon.ico' like

```dart
void handleGet(HttpRequest request) {
    int requestNumber = 1;
    print(requestNumber++); // This shows me the request number.
    print(request.uri); // This shows me the request from the client browser.
    if(request.requestedUri.path != '/favicon.ico') {
      request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
    } else {
      request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.OK;
    }
    request.response.close();
}
```

Comment: I could make the browser send the request to my Dart server side application starting with some string like "my_app_request", then check at the beginning of the handleGet for that specific string, right? This would solve the problem of responding to requests that my application are not programmed to. Is this a workaround or a real solution?

Comment: I don't think you can modify the `favicon.ico` request. You should just check on your server which requests you can or want to process and for all other requests you just send a proper response code like `HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND` (or similar if another error code fits better).
You should definitely cope with this issue on the server because this is what you can control. You can't control what users enter in their browsers address bar or what some 'agent' might send to your server.

Comment: I understand that, but I think I've explained it wrong. What I think would solve the issue is to develop the server side application in a way that it checks for the requestedUri.path to see if it matches to the ones that I want to respond. I would not change the requests from the browser. I just have to change my submit button action to send a specific string to my server.

Comment: Thanks, Günter! I'll adjust the handleGet in order to respond to specific requests! =)